# If $A$ is a rank one linear transformation, show there is a unique scalar $\alpha$ such that $A^2 = \alpha A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ is a rank one linear transformation, show there is a unique scalar $\alpha$ such that $A^2 = \alpha A$. Then, if $\alpha \neq 1$, show that $1-A$ is invertible.

This is problem 9, section 52 of *Halmos, Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces*. I have been thinking about this for a while, but my attempts have not produced any worthwhile results/progress.

Comment: Hint: $A=xy'$ for some vectors $x$ and $y$, then $A^2=...$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $R_t$ be a non-zero row of $A$. Then, for each $R_i$, $\exists \ \alpha_i$, such that $R_i = \alpha_i R_t$. Then, how may we represent $A$?

Comment: I suppose this means we can write every row as a linear combination of the first row. Hence, the matrix is really $A = \vec{c} \vec{a}_{1\cdot}'$ where $\vec{c}$ is a vector of scalars $\implies A^2 = (\vec{c} \vec{a}_{1\cdot}')(\vec{c} \vec{a}_{1\cdot}') = \vec{c} c \vec{a}_{1\cdot}= c A$. At least that's how my thinking goes. Thanks!

Comment: Upvote for providing a hint without the final answer :)